# How can I embed a stream from http://tv.majorleaguegaming.com onto a webpage?

Tags: video-streaming, embed, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

Unlike Youtube or any other streaming or video service MLG does not seem to have a built in embed button.  Is there anyway I can embed this into my webpage?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that MLG embed their stream by adding an iframe. For example they have used:

```
<iframe width="672" height="378" src="http://tv.majorleaguegaming.com/player/proofy?aid=mlg52_1" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

You should be able to copy it into your site in the same way.

Comment: Any idea why this happens when I use it?